# MatplotLib error : only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, typeerror

I'm trying to make a function for a data set. The function basically takes one of the feature names as a string, and then the function is supposed to return an x axis value and a y axis value which will be used to make a bar chart. The bar chart is supposed to show the correlation between a desired feature (in this case the sepal-length) and another fixed feature (in this case the 'species' classification).

This is what a sample of the data set looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBP7A.png)

```
def correlation_group(feature):
  y_axis = df[['species',feature]].groupby('species').mean()
  x_axis= df.species.unique()
  y = []
  for i in range(1) :
      y.append(y_axis[i:])
  print(y)

  return x_axis, y

y = 'sepal_length'
x,y = correlation_group(y)
print(y)
plt.bar(x,y)
```

The result I get after running this is the error:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-cd8e1ad8a982> in <module>
     12 x,y = correlation_group(y)
     13 print(y)
---> 14 plt.bar(x,y)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)
   2485         x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center',
   2486         data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2487     return gca().bar(
   2488         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
   2489         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1446         if data is None:
-> 1447             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448 
   1449         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2479         args = zip(left, bottom, width, height, color, edgecolor, linewidth)
   2480         for l, b, w, h, c, e, lw in args:
-> 2481             r = mpatches.Rectangle(
   2482                 xy=(l, b), width=w, height=h,
   2483                 facecolor=c,

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    740         """
    741 
--> 742         Patch.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    743 
    744         self._x0 = xy[0]

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, edgecolor, facecolor, color, linewidth, linestyle, antialiased, hatch, fill, capstyle, joinstyle, **kwargs)
     86         self.set_fill(fill)
     87         self.set_linestyle(linestyle)
---> 88         self.set_linewidth(linewidth)
     89         self.set_antialiased(antialiased)
     90         self.set_hatch(hatch)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in set_linewidth(self, w)
    391                 w = mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth']
    392 
--> 393         self._linewidth = float(w)
    394         # scale the dash pattern by the linewidth
    395         offset, ls = self._us_dashes

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `range(1)` - it will give only one value `i = 0` so you could run directly `y_axis[0:]` but this means the same as `y_axis`. And I don't understand why you append it to `y` - you create `y` with only one element `y_axis` - and maybe this is `size-1` array` which makes problem.. Why not `return x_axis, y_axis`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would add example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it.